# HTMLTabs CSS working in firefox and chrome but not in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I have one html tab CSS where it shows properly in Chrome and Firefox but not in Internet Explorer.

Problem here is that joint point of `li` with content is separated and is not joining in Internet Explorer

**css:**

```css
#header ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#header li {
    float: left;
    font: 10px arial,sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 0.24em 1em;
    color: #00c;
    width: 8em;
    text-align: center;
}

#header a:hover {
    background: #ddf;
}

#header #selected {
    border-color: black;
}

#header #selected a {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div id="header">
        <ul>
            <li name_id="tab1" id="selected">
            <a name="" type="hyperlink" href="#">tab1</a>
            </li>

            <li name_id="tab2">
            <a name="" type="hyperlink" href="#">tab2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="table-wrapper">
            <div id="table-scroll">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#">Test Value 1</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#">Test Value 2</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

[jsfiddle.net demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BZAGG/2/)

Comment: You could try adding a css reset first: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @bungdito Look at Jessel's below, it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Include the above `DOCTYPE` declaration in your html script.

Comment: Though above was missing but it did not help with the solution

Comment: Thanks John for your quick response, It got solved after fixing font size.

Comment: New web pages have no use for that doctype since 1999. Always use a strict doctype.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved if after reading this by setting my font size to small.  Weird!